# how to recognise the squrae marker in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, markers

In my project, it needs recognise the square marrker in the real time video input. In every frame,the square marker should be recoginzed stability.And the following codes was used to detected the square marker.however,it cause error in same frames,and i have try many methods but still useless.

```
gray_img = rgb2gray(img);
bw_img= im2bw(gray_img,0.35);  
[B,L] = bwboundaries(bw_img,'noholes');
se1=strel('square',30);
L_erode=imerode(L,se1,'same'); 
stats =[regionprops(L_erode); regionprops(not(L_erode))];
A=[stats.Area];
idx=find(A==min(A(A~=0)));
```

the test image is here:

[image]

Comment: what error it causes?

Comment: the codes return the centroid coordinate of the square marker, but in some frames, it return the wrong the coordinate.

Comment: The lights are brighter than the square object so those will compute with your current method.

Comment: That is the problem.In this scenario, the strel function was used  to detect all squares or rectangles in image regions.And i find in most frames, the position of square has the minimum area. hence, the centroid of the square can be derived. however,this algorithm is not accurate all the time.In some case, the minimum area does not corresponds to the position of the square. And i want to know how to get the accurate position of the square in this scenario.

Comment: I'd segment this using histograms. This will work as long as the image looks like this most of the time (there are no extra black things in the screen). If there are you may be bale to improve the histogram segmentation